# TbQuery voltar N registros

Tags: sql, delphi, delphi-7

No delphi se eu der um `TbQuery.prior` ele volta um registro.
Mas se eu quiser voltar N registros, por exemplo, quero voltar 5 registros. Alguém sabe se existe algum method no delphi que faça isso?

Comment: Só para ficar mas claro, você quer ir voltando de 5 em 5 registros?

Comment: Não necessariamente, posso voltar N vezes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o método `MoveBy(Distance: Integer)`.

Com este método você indica no parâmetro pra onde quer mover o *cursor* do registro atual.

Valores **positivos** movem o cursor para **frente** no dataSet e valores **negativos** para **trás**.

No seu exemplo use `TbQuery.MoveBy(-5);`

Comment: Valeu funcionou.

Comment: Que bom que funcionou. Se seu problema foi resolvido não esqueça de sinalizar http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers .